# Spring Boot custom Kubernetes readiness probe

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

I want to implement custom logic to determine readiness for my pod, and I went over this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.kubernetes-probes.external-state and they mention an example property:
`management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.include=readinessState,customCheck`

Question is - how do I override `customCheck`?
In my case I want to use HTTP probes, so the yaml looks like:

```
readinessProbe:
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  httpGet:
    path: /actuator/health
    port: 12345
```

So then again - where and how should I apply logic that would determine when the app is ready (just like the link above, i'd like to rely on an external service in order for it to be ready)

Answer (score 9):

To expand KrzysztofS's answer:

First, create a custom health indicator like this:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.availability.ReadinessStateHealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.boot.availability.ApplicationAvailability;
import org.springframework.boot.availability.AvailabilityState;
import org.springframework.boot.availability.ReadinessState;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyCustomReadinessIndicator extends ReadinessStateHealthIndicator {
  private final AtomicBoolean ready = new AtomicBoolean();

  public MyCustomReadinessIndicator(ApplicationAvailability availability) {
    super(availability);
  }

  @Override
  protected AvailabilityState getState(ApplicationAvailability applicationAvailability) {
    return ready.get()
        ? ReadinessState.ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
        : ReadinessState.REFUSING_TRAFFIC;
  }

  public void markAsReady() {
    if (ready.get()) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Already initialized");
    }
    ready.set(true);
  }
}
```

This must be a bean, or Spring won't be able to discover it.

`@Autowire` your component to your service or another component, and call its `markAsReady()` function when this indicator should switch into "ready" state.

Next, add the name of the bean<sup>1</sup> into "include" block for "readiness" group in your application.yaml file (if you're using application.properties, figure it out yourself).

```yaml
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      group:
        readiness:
          include: readinessState, myCustomReadinessIndicator
      show-components: always
      show-details: always
      probes:
        enabled: true
```

Next, try running your application and opening various Actuator endpoints.

| Endpoint | `ready` state of your indicator | HTTP response code | JSON response |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `/actuator/health` | `false` | 503 | `{` `"status": "OUT_OF_SERVICE",` `"components":` `{` `"myCustomReadinessIndicator":` `{` `"status": "OUT_OF_SERVICE"` `},` `"livenessState":` `{` `"status": "UP"` `},` `"readinessState":` `{` `"status": "UP"` `}` `},` `"groups": ["liveness", "readiness"]` `}` |
| `/actuator/health/liveness` | `false` | 200 | `{"status":"UP"}` |
| `/actuator/health/readiness` | `false` | 503 | `{` `"status": "OUT_OF_SERVICE",` `"components":` `{` `"myCustomReadinessIndicator":` `{` `"status": "OUT_OF_SERVICE"` `},` `"readinessState":` `{` `"status": "UP"` `}` `}` `}` |
| `/actuator/health` | `true` | 200 | `{` `"status": "UP",` `"components":` `{` `"myCustomReadinessIndicator":` `{` `"status": "UP"` `},` `"livenessState":` `{` `"status": "UP"` `},` `"readinessState":` `{` `"status": "UP"` `}` `},` `"groups": ["liveness", "readiness"]` `}` |
| `/actuator/health/liveness` | `true` | 200 | `{"status":"UP"}` |
| `/actuator/health/readiness` | `true` | 200 | `{` `"status": "UP",` `"components":` `{` `"myCustomReadinessIndicator":` `{` `"status": "UP"` `},` `"readinessState":` `{` `"status": "UP"` `}` `}` `}` |

Now, you need to set `/actuator/health/readiness` in your readiness probe's path

```yaml
readinessProbe:
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  httpGet:
    path: /actuator/health/readiness
    port: 12345
```

Related: set liveness probe's path to `/actuator/health/liveness` not to `/actuator/health`, since `/actuator/health` will return 503 if your indicator isn't ready yet, even though `livenessState` is "UP".

---

<sup>1</sup> Bean name is usually camel-cased name of the class, starting with lowercase letter, but you can override it by providing name in component annotation: `@Component("overriddenName")`

Answer (score 5):

customCheck is a key for your custom HealthIndicator. The key for a given HealthIndicator is the name of the bean without the HealthIndicator suffix

You can read:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.health.writing-custom-health-indicators

You are defining readinessProbe, so probably hiting /actuator/health/readiness is a better choice.

```
public class CustomCheckHealthIndicator extends AvailabilityStateHealthIndicator {

    private final YourService yourService;

    public CustomCheckHealthIndicator(ApplicationAvailability availability, YourService yourService) {
        super(availability, ReadinessState.class, (statusMappings) -> {
            statusMappings.add(ReadinessState.ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC, Status.UP);
            statusMappings.add(ReadinessState.REFUSING_TRAFFIC, Status.OUT_OF_SERVICE);
        });
        this.yourService = yourService;
    }

    @Override
    protected AvailabilityState getState(ApplicationAvailability applicationAvailability) {
        if (yourService.isInitCompleted()) {
            return ReadinessState.ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC;
        } else {
            return ReadinessState.REFUSING_TRAFFIC;
        }
    }

}
```